# Simple web server with authentication

Tags: java

I want to implement a simple web server (like apache), with static content. The server must offer authentication by username and password or by IP address.

Source code or any usefull tutorial will be really helpful.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: *"Source code or any usefull tutorial will be really helpful."*  Showing effort and asking a (specific) question would also be helpful.  As it stands, this is 'not a real question'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want it really simple you can try JDK 1.6 `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`, it has also basic authentication mechanizm:

```
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8888), 0);
    HttpContext cc  = server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
    cc.setAuthenticator(new BasicAuthenticator("test") {
        @Override
        public boolean checkCredentials(String user, String pwd) {
            return user.equals("test") && pwd.equals("test");
        }
    });
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
```

If you want it to be simple like apache then try Jetty http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/ it is a real web server which is easy to use and it can be embedded in a Java standalone app.

Answer (score 5):

Since `Java 1.6`, there's a builtin `HTTP server`.
This is one [Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html)

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
}

static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        String response = "This is the response";
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}

}
```

Execute it and go to `http://localhost:8000/test` and you'll see the response

Also, [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/): [Example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty)

Comment: thanks for really fast answer, but how can i add to your code  authentification? Do I must use Spring 3 security mentioned below?

Comment: not necessary, that's your logic!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the source code of [NanoHTTPPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NanoHTTPD). It's a very simple web server written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The technology, that you'd probably need, is called `Spring 3 security`. It's quite often used framework for `java EE` apps. Try to google it. I'm sure you'll find lot of useful informations and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Realm if you want to make a JEE6 application in a glassfish server.
Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html